MS Access Query- Update Table A SET COL A3 is sum of value of Table B--> COL B2 where Table B COL B1 between Table A--> Col A1 and Col A2
I want to make a sum of col B2 from Table B and update Column A3 from Table A
using where condition--> where do sum where sequence number between Column A1 and Column A2.
For Example--> Table B Col B1 between 0-10= sum of values of Column B1 i.e 21.2
Table B



Column B1
Column B2




0
0


1
1.5


2
2.0


3
0


4
1.0


5
2.5


6
4.5


7
8.5


8
0


9
0


10
1.2


11
0


12
0


13
0


14
0


15
0


16
0


17
0


18
0


19
0


20
0



Table A



Column A1
Column A2
Column A3




0
10
21.2


10
20
0



enter image description here
I made and ran below query on SQL Server, working perfectly fine, but same query I am trying to run in MS Access, getting Error

operation must be an updateable query

Update Table A 
SET Column A3 = (SELECT SUM(Column B2) from Table B
WHERE Table B.Column B1 between Table A.Column A1 and Table A.Column A2);

Can someone help why the same query is working on SQL server but in MS Access throwing error?

This is a common topic. Access does not allow UPDATE with aggregate query as source. If you must do this in Access, use VBA or domain aggregate function. However, it is usually ill-advised approach to save aggregate data - calculate when needed. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed. More info which notes exception http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html
